# Angular-ui Bootstrap Error require is not defined

Tags: node.js, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-carousel

I am implementing the angular-ui carousel. After adding jspm packages to existing project I see following error in my console.

:3000/jspm_packages/bower/angular-ui/bootstrap@1.2.2/index.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined$ @ system.js:4
system.js:4 Uncaught Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    Evaluating localhost:3000/jspm_packages/bower/angular-ui/bootstrap@1.2.2/index.js$ @ system.js:4
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) Uncaught Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    Evaluating localhost:3000/jspm_packages/bower/angular-ui/bootstrap@1.2.2/index.js
    Evaluating localhost:3000/jspm_packages/bower/angular-ui/bootstrap@1.2.2.js
    Error loading localhost:3000/js/bootstrap.js

Comment: did you resolve this issue?